# Material React Table dragging on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui, material-react-table

I have a problem with [MaterialReactTableV2](https://www.material-react-table.com) because I cannot drag rows or columns on the mobile screen. Everything works great on PC. I'm just a beginner in javascript and I haven't found a solution on the internet.
Is there any solution for this as I would really like to avoid implementing other premade tables.

Answer (score 0):

For MaterialReactTableV2, mobile dragging isn't supported out-of-the-box due to touch event complexities. A workaround is to integrate third-party libraries like `react-dnd` (React Drag and Drop) designed for touch support. This involves wrapping your table component with `react-dnd`'s touch backend. Since you're a beginner, it might take some time to implement. Check out `react-dnd` documentation for guidance on setup. Unfortunately, without diving into custom solutions or other table libraries, options are limited. It's a common hurdle in mobile web app development.